# Embedding WP into my HTML

Tags: wordpress

I'm redesigning my website http://point-studios.com/ the blog will be only one section of about 7 sections.

I don't want all the site to be placed in the WP templating system for the blog to work.
Is there any way I could embed my WP into one section of the site ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just install Wordpress into a subdirectory (ie /blog) and run it there rather than in the root.  Your site would run normally using your own HTML but if you visited http://www.yoursite.com/blog you'd be accessing the Wordpress install.